# module initialization error: Error at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18) at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)

Tags: node.js, file, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am working with aws lambda.

I have one of my `.p8` file which is being used to send `apns` notification. Since I cannot use relative or absolute path because it's a server less. I have to read it from s3 url. And for that I made this

```
let file = ''
https.get("https://my_file_path.p8", response => {
  console.log(response)
})

 this.options = {
    production: this.production,
    token: {
      key: file,
      keyId: this.keyId,
      teamId: this.teamId
    }
  }
```

Now How I can append that file buffer which is on S3?

Thank you!!!

Comment: do you want to read a file from s3

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes

Comment: did you tried fs package

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan Yes but it's server less. I am getting above error

Comment: Check my answer. Let me know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below snippet. Try using the absolute path instead of relative '__dirname'

```
'use strict'

let fs = require("fs")
let path = require("path")

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
        fs.readFile(__dirname +'/somefile.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err
        })
}
```

**Update**

If you want to use AWS - S3 instead of those npm packages you can use AWS-SDK for nodejs to read the content of S3 file.
You can refer this [**tutorial**](https://faragta.com/aws-lambda/read-file-from-s3.html) for reading file from S3.